# Get text from <tr> and add to img alt in another <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to copy text from a blogger blogspot caption table and add it to the img alt, so that it will appear in the fancybox slideshow as the title/caption.

So, this is the HTML I have :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tr-caption-container" style="float: right; text-align: right;"><tbody>
<tr>           <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="URL"><img align="right" alt="" src="URL" title="Ghostly Waves in the Valle de Rocas" width="320" /></a></td>         </tr>
<tr>           <td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">This is my Caption</td>         </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And my script is:

```
   $("tr-caption").each(function(){
     var Caption = $(this).text();

     if (Caption && Caption !== ''){
         $(this).parent(img).attr('alt', Caption );
     }
});
```

And this is the output I'd hope for....

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tr-caption-container" style="float: right; text-align: right;"><tbody>
<tr>           <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="URL"><img align="right" alt="This is my Caption" src="URL" title="Ghostly Waves in the Valle de Rocas" width="320" /></a></td>         </tr>
<tr>           <td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">This is my Caption</td>         </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

But it's not working...

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NCqW2/6/

Any help greatly appreciated!  Thanks for taking some time to look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
$(this).parent(img).attr('alt', Caption );
```

with

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('img').attr('alt', Caption );
```

should do it.

Comment: Or you could use http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/ and just do `$(this).prevInDOM('img').attr('alt', Caption );` - *Big disclaimer: I wrote it. Posting it here purely because it precisely fits the usecase.*

Comment: That was pretty darn quick!!....so quick I can't mark it as right yet!  Thanks guys, a really great help, and saved me a mountain of time no doubt!